# DateTime.ParseExact throwing exception

Tags: c#, datetime, string-to-datetime

I'm pretty sure that I am making some very stupid error but this is driving me insane.

I am trying to do the following:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("08/24/2016 12:00:00 AM", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But I keep getting the following exception: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

I have tried:
"M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt"
"MM'/'dd'/'yyyy HH:mm:ss tt"
"M'/'dd'/'yyyy HH:mm:ss tt"

But nothing working so far... Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It works for me, I get the output 24/08/2016 12:00:00

Comment: Change the format string to this:`"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`HH` is looking for a 24 hour format, but you're also passing in `AM` and specifying `tt` - the parser can't deal with that.  You need to either look for a 12-hour based string:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("08/24/2016 12:00:00 AM", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

using `hh`, or remove the `AM`/`tt` part.

Comment: A good way to remember this is is `hh` are "small hours", `HH` are "big hours".

Comment: I knew it was something small... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use  `hh` for 12 hour format instead of `HH` for 24 hour format. This information is already in `AM/PM` and can't be handled twice by the method.

```
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("08/24/2016 12:00:00 AM", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I knew it was something small... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `hh` instead of `HH` because `HH` is used for 24 hour format and you are also specifying `am` `pm` in format

```
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("08/24/2016 12:00:00 AM", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I knew it was something small... thanks!